# What color of gem is best to use in an amplifier?

Tags: gemcraft-labyrinth

Same color as the gem amplified, that's for sure, but is pure better than triple color? Maybe double?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what effect do you like. Pure green has more poison damage than double or triple color gems, but they have aditional efects. The gameplay is not very different if you use 1 green 1 yellow or 2 green/yellow gems (this is not 100% true if they are at very different spots)

Answer (score 0):

Now i have it figured out.

- If you want to amplify the special of the gem use pure color
- If tou want to amplify the damage use double or triple (depending which has more bonus to damage)

For example:

- You have OLB gem in trap. B mixed in just for extra damage from triple gem. You want the highest possible Mana gain and Chain hit - use two amplifiers, one with pure Orange, second with pure Lime.
- You have LYB gem in a tower. Again B mixed in just for extra damage. For highest damage you want a LYB in the Amplifier - it gets extra damage from triple gem, and this gives higher damage for the amplified gem.

  In the last case I combine grade 1 B with grade 1 L, then combine it with grade 2 YL, then with grade 3 YL and so on. This way i have triple gem with Y and L components staying and almost the same, highest possible level.